# How we can write delimiter like sep=, using CsvHelper library?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

we're using CsvHelper library to export some information from our application, our clients normally use Excel to see the results

[image]
*(sample of correctly opened data)*

everything was working well until I tested my generated files in another machine with Format set on **German(Austria)** which I found out that excel would not parse it correctly anymore which is understandable because **,** has a different meaning in this format.
[image]

adding **sep=,** in the first line seems to fix the issue, but I couldn't find in CsvHelper documents that How we can achieve this. so the question is

**How we can write delimiter like sep=, or anything with similar effect using CsvHelper library?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside the `CsvWriter` class there is an aptly named `WriteExcelSeparator()` that should do it.

Depending on how you use the library, you can even:

```
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
csv.Configuration.HasExcelSeparator = true;
```

If you use the `WriteRecords`, use the second way, while if you use  `WriteHeader`/`WriteRecord` use the first one.

```
csv.WriteExcelSeparator();
csv.WriteHeader<Simple>();
csv.WriteRecord( record );
```

Comment: @user3473830 Note that everything I wrote, I found easily by going to the source code of the CsvHelper https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper, and doing a search for *sep*

Comment: I'm really embarrassed, our company was using csvhelper version 2.5 which doesn't have this feature( I checked right now), I mistakenly only checked our local clone repository and didn't consider that this feature maybe added in newer versions, thanks for your help again.

Comment: Seems like Excel specific codes are removed from the library.

Comment: @YusufTarıkGünaydın It seems to be a different question... You should post it as question with a full working example.

Comment: @xanatos I updated a project to use CsvHelper version 6 and the method WriteExcelSeparator() seems to not exist anymore. I couldn't see anything in the changelog http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log. How does one handle it in version 6?

Comment: @less I don't use that library... I had done some research for this reply.

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/847), all Excel-specific code was removed from CsvHelper (I don't think this was a good decision, BTW)

Comment: Latest version 22.0 is readonly `string Delimiter { get; }`

Comment: @Kiquenet They moved it to a configurator object: see the example [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/3b14b70fd1e9ce742375fbb116799b19fd0e7ccd/tests/CsvHelper.Tests/Parsing/DelimiterTests.cs)

Answer (score 33):

They first changed it to being a parameter of CsvConfiguration and as of 8th of March 2021 it is

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Delimiter = ";", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
```

Likely they will change it again in the future ;)

Comment: And I was wondering why it was an readonly field all of a sudden. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

since csvHelper does support the excel specific methods, you can do this now..

```
csvWriter.WriteField("sep=,", false);
csvWriter.NextRecord();
csvWriter.WriteRecords(dataToExport);
```