# How to properly put CSV data into custom class records in C#?

Tags: c#, csv, record

I want to put a data from simple csv file into the records containing custom made class.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;    // for accessing the files
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;  // to call a list enumerable
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

namespace Reading_CSV_Files
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadCSVFile(@"C:\path_to_my_file\file.csv");
            
        }



    public static void ReadCSVFile(String filePath)
        {
            if (filePath == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath) )
            {
                using (var foodFileCSVReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    //var records = foodFileCSVReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
                    var records = foodFileCSVReader.GetRecords<Pizza>().ToList();
                    // replace dynamic type argument on our records

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Pizza 
    {
        // attributes
        [Name("Name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Name("PLN_Cost")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The csv file looks like this:
[Screenshot from csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUHbD.png)
The file was saved as comma separated. I found some advices with manual setting it up, but currently it says, this field is read-only.

> CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: Header with name 'Name'[0] was not found.
> Header with name 'PLN_Cost'[0] was not found.

Comment: If you open the CSV file in a hex editor, does it start with the (hex) bytes 4E 61 6D ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by hex editor. I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Please see [Can I hex edit a file in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724591/1115360) for instructions.

Comment: Yes. It starts like this: 4E 61 6D 65 3B 50 4C

Comment: Aha! That's "Name;PL", so you need to tell the CSV reader to use semicolons as the separator instead of commas. You didn't give a link to the exact CSV helper you're using, so I can't tell you the exact instruction, but you should be able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: I found that in previous versions it could be set up, but currently it says that it's read-only.I'm using CSVHeelper 27.0.2 by Josh Close on visual studio 2019. .Net in version 4.8

Comment: @Beginner_in_R Does [How we can write delimiter like sep=, using CsvHelper library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532784/1115360) help?

Comment: It shows red foodFileCSVReader.WriteField("sep=,", false); and says that does not contain definition for WriteField

Comment: @Andrew Morton I don't know if that helps, but I copied and pasted all content from this file into the google sheet and downloaded it. Now it works fine. Maybe its something related to settings on my OS (polish).

Comment: The usual CSV separator in mainland Europe is the semi-colon because a comma is used as the decimal separator. I guess that Google Sheet uses commas in CSV files and full stops `.` for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is going to be using CSV files which might have a comma or semi-colon as the separator, you could read the first line and set the separator to either of those, like this:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Pizza
        {
            // attributes
            [Name("Name")]
            public String Name { get; set; }

            [Name("PLN_Cost")]
            public decimal Price { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Name} - {Price}";
            }
        }

        public static List<Pizza> ReadCSVFile(String filePath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return new List<Pizza>();
            }

            var sep = ";";

            /* Check the header for the separator character to use. */
            string headerLine = File.ReadLines(filePath).First();
            if (headerLine?.IndexOf(',') >= 0) { sep = ","; }

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                {
                    Delimiter = sep,
                    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
                };

                using (var foodFileCSVReader = new CsvReader(sr, config))
                {
                    return foodFileCSVReader.GetRecords<Pizza>().ToList();

                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pp = ReadCSVFile(@"C:\temp\PizzaPrices.csv");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", pp));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Note that it is better to use the `decimal` type for money instead of the `double` type.

You might need additional code to set the decimal separator to be used.