# Convert CSV in XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv, visual-studio-2019

I wrote this piece of code that allows me to read a CSV file and convert it to an XML file.
I have a problem, if inside the CSV file there are semicolons (;) the program cannot read the data instead, if there are commas (,) that delimit the words the program can read the data and to insert them correctly in the XML file.
could you find a way to replace the semicolon (;) with the comma (,)?
Thank you very much!! :)

This is the code:

```
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipes");

        using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(path))
        {
            reader.ReadHeaders();

            while (reader.ReadRecord())
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipes");

                writer.WriteAttributeString("PlantNo", reader["id_imp"]);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("No", reader["nome_frm"]);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", reader["desc_frm"]);

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();


        logText.Text += DateTime.Now + " Convertion Completed\n";
        logText.Text += DateTime.Now + " Saving file to: " + savepath + "\n";
        try
        {
            logText.Text += DateTime.Now + " File save completed!\n";
            logText.Text += DateTime.Now + " process END\n";
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post code as text directly into your question and not as an image.

Comment: Also, I believe CsvHelper has a way to set the delimiter. That should be preferable to changing your input. I could be wrong though.

Comment: You didn't post the code of your `CsvReader` but it should support different cultures so you can initialize it with a `CultureInfo`. And then you can pick the correct separator by the `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ListSeparator` property. This is how also Excel produces semicolon-delimited CSV files when the current culture represents a language where comma is used for decimal separator.

Comment: I've found a topic for changing the delimiter for CsvHelper. I hope it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437440/how-we-can-write-delimiter-like-sep-using-csvhelper-library

Comment: Write your own CSVReader that uses string split instead of a 3rd party app that doesn't work.  It is only a few lines of code.

Comment: @Andrea Ruffo You want to write a method to replace all ‘;’ in the original file with ‘,’ as a temporary CSV file. Then for you to read the conversion operation. Finally, delete the temporary files. Is it such a process?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass into `CsvReader` constructor a `CsvConfiguration` to change the default delimiter ([which is based on the current CultureInfo](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/)):

> The culture is used to determine the default delimiter, default line ending, and formatting when type converting.

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
{ 
    Delimiter = "," 
}))
{
    csv.Read();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write your own `CsvReader`:

```
    public static List<Model> ReadCsv(string path)
    {
        var modelList = new List<Model>();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var splittedLine = line.Split(';');

                    var model = new Model();

                    for (var i = 0; i < splittedLine.Length; i++)
                    {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                model.FirstColumn = splittedLine[i];
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                model.SecondColumn = splittedLine[i];
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                model.ThirdColumn = Convert.ToInt32(splittedLine[i]);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    modelList.Add(model);
                }
            }
        }

        return modelList;
    }
```